# Using the same HDD with macOS and Windows

Tags: macos, windows, storage, hdd

Is it possible to use the same external HDD for both macOS and Windows? For example, can I use it as backup storage for both systems?

If so, should it have at least 2 partitions?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this with TWO External HDs so I can guarantee my advice is correct.

It's possible **IF** you have (third party) software installed that let's MacOS, Windows, or both **READ AND WRITE** the other filesystem (the driver's that come with Mac OS are **READ-ONLY**).

Otherwise you will need separate partitions for each OS. If you are using Time Machine I **VERY STRONGLY RECOMMEND** you give it a dedicated partition regardless of drivers!

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree! I would recommend formatting the external drive (unless you're using it for time machine) as ExFAT! This way neither MacOS nor Windows need drivers to access the data!

Comment: Depends on intended use. ExFAT was a 4gb file size limit that is sometimes unrealistic for modern file sizes. For example, if the poster wants to share his iTunes library between OSes like I do and has lots of videos the 4gb limit may get in the way.

Comment: @BryanDunphy you're thinking of FAT32.  ExFat's file size limit (peta/exabyte range) dwarfs the largest drives available.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT

Comment: Okay, I don't use ExFAT myself so I got confused.

Comment: Last point. ExFAT was designed for SSDs and has about 5x SLOWER reading and writing speed on physical disks (like most external drives) than HFS+ or NTFS!

Comment: Where did you get such info about the design purpose of ExFAT format? Provide references. Otherwise your "last point" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Wikipedia article on "ExFAT" search for it then "solid" in the article.